# MongoEngine recursive embedding

Tags: python, flask, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I am trying to model a document with mongoengine but I can't figure out how I can do recursive embedding. For example I want to do something like this

```
class NavigationHelper(EmbeddedDocument):
    name = StringField()
    url = URLField()
    sub_menus = EmbeddedDocumentListField(NavigationHelper)
```

I will use this to create a navigation tree with infinite sub-menu possibility. for example

-menu-1

--sub-menu-1-1

---sub-menu-1-1-1

---sub-menu-1-1-2

----sub-menu-1-1-2-1

-menu-2

is there any way for to model this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can model that with one high level `Document` and a list of `EmbeddedDocument`.

```
from mongoengine import Document, EmbeddedDocument, StringField, URLField, EmbeddedDocumentListField

# The embeddedDocument of sub-menus
class NavigationSubMenu(EmbeddedDocument):
    name = StringField()
    url = URLField()
    sub_menus = EmbeddedDocumentListField('NavigationSubMenu')


# The document for the main menus
class NavigationMenu(Document):
    name = StringField()
    url = URLField()
    sub_menus = EmbeddedDocumentListField(NavigationSubMenu)
```

The example you gave would be created by:

```
docs = [
    NavigationMenu(name='1',
                   sub_menus=[
                       NavigationSubMenu(name='1-1',
                                         sub_menus=[
                                             NavigationSubMenu(name='1-1-1'),
                                             NavigationSubMenu(name='1-1-2',
                                                               sub_menus=[
                                                                   NavigationSubMenu(name='1-1-2-1')
                                                               ])
                                         ])
                   ]
                   ),
    NavigationMenu(name='2')
]

for doc in docs:
    doc.save()

docs = NavigationMenu.objects()

for doc in docs:
    print(doc.name)
    while len(doc.sub_menus) > 0:
        for sub_menu in doc.sub_menus:
            print(sub_menu.name)
            doc = sub_menu

>> 1
>> 1-1
>> 1-1-1
>> 1-1-2
>> 1-1-2-1
>> 2
```

If you save this, you will get 2 documents. One for each high level `NavigationMenu`.

Comment: This one gives mongoengine.errors.InvalidDocumentError: Invalid data to create a `NavigationHelper` instance.
sub_menus - type object 'EmbeddedDocument' has no attribute '_class_name' error

Comment: The code I posted here works. Note in the `class NavigationSubMenu(EmbeddedDocument)` the `sub_menus = EmbeddedDocumentListField(EmbeddedDocument)` doesn't reference itself, but rather, the `EmbeddedDocument`. It is a little dangerous because you will be able to put any `EmbeddedDocument` there, not only `NavigationSubMenu`, but you can make sure you are consistent.

Comment: Check again your code, and try to follow my steps. No where in  my answer I used `NavigationHelper`, so that error is coming from your code.

Comment: only difference with our codes is the name of the class. if I use your code without changing I am still getting the same error. mongoengine.errors.InvalidDocumentError: Invalid data to create a `NavigationSubMenu` instance.
sub_menus - type object 'EmbeddedDocument' has no attribute '_class_name'

Comment: what python version are you running? Btw, try this source code (https://codeshare.io/5zq39D)

Comment: I am using 3.6.4 only difference with our code is you are storing your data in a variable and I use MongoDB. and when I try to query my DB it gives that error. it gives the error when I execute Navigation.objects().first() to get the 1st item in my Navigation document

Comment: Sorry about this. I edited my answer. Check the `NavigationSubMenu` again. Apparently you  can do a recursive reference with a `str`, (`sub_menus = EmbeddedDocumentListField('NavigationSubMenu')`). Got this from (https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/1386)

Comment: Awesome! Learned something new myself ;)